# Can't add rewrite rules to web.config .net core

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I have created a new web project with .net core.
The default web config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I open this config file I get a warning stating:

> The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'aspNetCore'.

But it let's me build and run my project.
My project is an angular application, so I want to add **html5mode**.
To do this, I should be able to add my rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- AngularJS Html5model -->
    <rule name="AngularJS Html5model" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem is, as soon as I add my rules to my web.config file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- AngularJS Html5model -->
        <rule name="AngularJS Html5model" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My application stops working. It's like it can't figure out what is a static file or not. Any static file can't be found now.
Looking at the rule, it statics that any file should be redirected to "/". 
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [this is a known error](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/43) and won't be fixed until the end of this year. There is a workaround though.
I needed to add a **RouteBuilder** to my **Startup** class:

```
var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app);

routeBuilder.MapGet("{*anything}", context =>
{
    context.Response.Redirect("/index.html");
    return Task.FromResult(0);
});

var routes = routeBuilder.Build();
app.UseRouter(routes);
```

This won't work by itself, you need to add the:

```
services.AddRouting();
```

to the **ConfigureServices** method.
here is my **Startup** class in its entirety:

```
public class Startup
{

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Set up our images
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"images")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/images")
        });

        var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app);

        routeBuilder.MapGet("{*anything}", context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/index.html");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        var routes = routeBuilder.Build();
        app.UseRouter(routes);
    }
}
```